# Calculating polygon main direction and creating line out of it

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, linestring, direction

I would like to find out the orientation of a polygon and create a line of that direction.
See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A true *weighted* orientation is non-trivial; I'd say the `ST_LongestLine` within a polygon is the best approximation, and will yield consistent results over multiple iterations.

- To get your initial *Polygons* with a column `dir` in degrees of the
  main orientation:

  ```
  SELECT <some_column_1>,
         ...
         <some_column_n>,
         DEGREES(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(ll), ST_EndPoint(ll))) AS dir,
         <geom_column>
  FROM (
    SELECT <some_column_1>,
           ...
           <some_column_n>,
           <geom_column>,
           ST_LongestLine(<geom_column>, <geom_column>) AS ll
    FROM <polygon_layer> 
  ) q;
  ```
- To get the *Linestring* of the main orientation, with column `dir`:

  ```
  SELECT *,
         DEGREES(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_EndPoint(geom))) AS dir
  FROM (
    SELECT <some_column_1>,
           ...
           <some_column_n>,
           ST_LongestLine(<geom_column>, <geom_column>) AS geom
    FROM <polygon_layer>
  ) q;
  ```

Comment: if you have the `SFCGAL` backend you could create the medial axis (`ST_ApproximateMedialAxis`) and average the azimuths of all resulting line segments based on their weighted length to the total length of the medial axis multiline. I might add this as another answer later (or someone else drops by with this idea), would need some testing first, though (and some time to do that...).

Comment: Ok great - if you could, that would be great - thanks

Comment: @user1655130 out of interest I might...but that might just as well not yield proper results. this above, however, does.

Comment: Hi, there are two geom fields returned and as a result I am not able  to run the first part of the select query - apart from that, I think it will work super.

Comment: So, I have updated the query to the following:                                  `SELECT *,
       DEGREES(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(q.geom), ST_EndPoint(q.longline))) AS dir
FROM (
SELECT a.id,
  a.geom,
        ST_LongestLine(a.geom, b.geom) as longline
  FROM floodplainw AS a
  JOIN floodplainw AS b
    ON a.id = b.id) as q;`            But dir is empty

Comment: @user1655130 not quite sure what you mean, but you don't need the extra `a.geom` in the sub-query: `longline` in your example is the line geometry already. for why `dir` is empty: you are using `a.geom` in `ST_StartPoint` where it should be `longline`, too. ah, or do you want the polygon geometry with an extra field for `dir`?

Comment: @user1655130 I updated the query to return the polygon geometry instead of the line geometry

Comment: This is fantastic - thanks. Finally, from this line layer that is created - is it possible to create perpendicullar lines to it? Thanks so much - this is brilliant

Comment: @user1655130 yes, e.g. [`ST_OffsetCurve`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html); note that the units given as distance will be in units of your data's CRS.

Comment: Cool, I'm looking for something that transects both sides of the line at every 15 meter intervals. Thanks for all of your help with this. I will check out ST_OffestCurve

Comment: @user1655130 ah man...I misread 'perpendicular' and thought you meant 'parallel'. `ST_OffsetCurve` is no use to you!!! also, getting perpendicular lines in a pattern is not as simple...consider searching in the board or ask a new question for that. mi scusi...

Comment: @user1655130 btw., if you intend to create a symbology for a map display this way: don't. with the azimuth of that line you can make a polygon fill pattern in e.g. QGIS that does the job for you.